# How to add image to page header with PageEvent

Tags: itext

I failed to find an example of how to add an image to the header of every page.

In the itext in action 2nd edition I found this:

> If your watermark is an image, you have options: you can add it with the PdfContent-
>   Byte.addImage() method, or you can wrap it in a ColumnText object, or you can put it
>   inside a cell in a table.

So I tried:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    try {
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.saveState();
        cb.beginText();
        cb.addImage(image);
        cb.addTemplate(total, document.right()/2, document.top() + 8);
        cb.restoreState();
        cb.endText();
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageHeader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting:

> com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced begin/end text operators.

Could someone please provide me a simple example of how to accomplish this?

P.s. My itext version is 5.4, so I can't use HeaderFooter object.

**EDIT:**
I failed to accomplish what I wanted through PDFContentByte.addImage(), but I managed to do it using a table:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.setTotalWidth(150f);
    table.setLockedWidth(true);
    table.addCell(new Celula.Builder(image).borda(0).build());
    table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, (document.right() + document.rightMargin()) / 2 - logo.getScaledWidth(), document.top() + 70f, writer.getDirectContent());
}
```

Comment: What happens if you get rid of all the `cb.*` things except for `addImage()` and `addTemplate()`? You're not performing text actions and you aren't modifying the stack so you shouldn't need to perform those actions.

Comment: I still get the same error if I remove those rows.

Answer (score 1):

Several things are wrong in your code snippet. More things may be wrong outside your code snippet.

In your code snippet: you nest `saveState()`/`restoreState()` with `beginText()`/`endText()`. Change this to:

```
cb.saveState();
...
cb.beginText();
...
cb.endText();
...
cb.restoreState();
```

You are creating a text object (using `beginText()`/`endText()`), but you're using illegal operators inside this text object. A text object is invalid if you don't use `setFontAndSize()` and also: you're not adding any text inside the text block (the Form XObject doesn't count, because it probably has a text block of its own).

The coordinates in your `addTemplate()` method are wrong: `cb.addTemplate(total, document.right()/2, document.top() + 8);`

- `document.right() / 2` is only correct if `document.left()` equals 0.
- `document.top() + 8` adds the content outside the visible area of the page (`document.top() - 8` would be better).

You add the image with `addImage()`, but we don't know if you defined coordinates for that image.

You quote from the book I wrote, but being the author of that book, I have the feeling that you didn't read what I wrote.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. You're right, although I read the entire book 1 or 2 years ago, I needed to read a few chapters again. I just thought I would be able to do that reading only the section related to page events.
After reading it again I found a few mistakes related to the template size and the document margins. Even after that I wasn't able to add an image to header through PDFContentByte.
Fortunately, as edited in my original post, I managed to accomplish what I needed though one of the other ways cited in your book.